# How to run consoleLog on Linux for eclipse product?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, terminal, eclipse-rcp

I want to see the logs for my eclipse product on runtime. When I use -consoleLog runtime command for Windows it works and opens console. However, for Linux based OS I can't find any solution. I tried "-console","-Debug", "-terminal" but I can't achieve anything.

What to do to open a terminal or any other application to see logs on runtime for eclipse product?

Answer (score 0):

Try to start eclipse in a terminal window and look into that terminal.